# How to redirect all users but me properly to another page with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to temporarily redirect all visitors to a new site to a under_construction.php page while I finish the site, but allowing me to see the real site. I've come up with the following:

```
Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/under_construction\.php$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/under_construction.php [R=302,L]

//Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Address 127.0.0.1 will be actually my visible IP address.

My problem is that under_construction.php fetches images from the /img/ folder which of course are not properly displayed. How can I include that folder in the rewrite rule?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you really sure, that 127.0.0.1 will be your (online) IP-Address?

Comment: why not simply http-authenticate that folder? http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: Yes... I will change it to the real address... Just didn't want to show what my IP is publicly

Comment: ah, ok, it wasn't clear to me, that 127 only was a placeholder. ...you never know...